# Win32 CTRL-ALT-DEL -> task manager kills OpenGL somehow

Tags: c, winapi, opengl, sdl-2

WINAPI:  I have a simple Win32 application and an OpenGL context.

- CAUSE) If I do CTRL-ALT-DELETE and click task manager ...
- EFFECT) the application window is black until it is resized. OpenGL will not render.

With a great deal of experimentation, I have largely overcome this huge annoyance ...

- Unlikable partial solution --- I cheat resizing the window with no redraw as such, "mostly" tricking Windows

Code:

```
case WM_SYNCPAINT:
    SetWindowPos (hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | 
                        SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOREDRAW | SWP_NOSIZE |  SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
    RedrawWindow (hwnd, NULL, 0, RDW_NOERASE );
    SetWindowPos (hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOOWNERZORDER |
                         SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE |  SWP_SHOWWINDOW );
    break;
```

D) However, it is still a suboptimal solution with some minor side effects.

- QUESTION 1: Why is my OpenGL getting killed, recreating the context doesn't even work.
- QUESTION 2: There has to be a real way to solve this problem without hiding the window and showing it again which causes some repainting side-effects ... does anyone have a solution.

Although not directly related, SDL2 has this problem as well and I often cross-check against their code for winapi messaging/drawing issues like this and their codebase doesn't have a solution and I see this issue posted around the internet for other things like Glut and such.  This seems to be a problem that rears its ugly head even in common OpenGL toolkits and such.

Comment: It's to be expected that OpenGL operation ceases while the Windows exclusive operation screen mode (used for everything that regular applications shall not be able to intercept: UAC, user switch, password entry, screen locking, Ctrl-Alt-Del menu) is active. However upon return normal operation should continue for OpenGL (Direct3D processes might receive a GPU lost event). Anyway, which GPU do you use and which drivers do you have installed?

Comment: Intel/ATI Radeon Mobility, drivers that came installed by OEM (2012 era).  Didn't know it could be GPU specific.  I may try some other Windows machines to see how they react.

Comment: But short version, aside from resize or my trick above which is essentially resize, even recreating a gl context won't restore rendering.  And as you noted, a number of other similar situations you noted cause the problem too.

Comment: I suggest you install the original vendor drivers from AMD/ATI and Intel. Windows doesn't ship proper OpenGL drivers by itself and instead relies on a Direct3D based OpenGL emulation layer; if that layer looses the GPU you'll likely see that behavior.

Comment: That is useful insight on the nature of the drivers shipped (i.e. Direct3D lost surface).  Updating drivers though isn't a programming suggestion however, there are still going to be plenty of those drivers in the wild.  Thanks for your insight into the nature of the issue, it appears I will have to live with my partial solution, which is about 90% acceptable but can cause a slightly painting glitch.

Comment: Well, you can always query the version/vendor of the OpenGL implementation, and if the emulation layer is detected show the user a message.